# codeforce - 548 dragons and princesses

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm working on a problem called **"Dragons and Princesses":**

Once upon a time there lived the Knight. Being very courageous he decided to make a long journey full of fights and adventures. The map of this journey can be represented as a row with n cells numbered from 1 to n from left to right. Initially the Knight is located at the leftmost cell (cell number 1). He should pass all the cells one by one and finish his way at the rightmost cell (cell number n). He is not allowed to move back or skip some cells, he will visit all the cells from the first to the last.

Each cell except the first one contains either a dragon or a princess. Each dragon has a chest with gold coins. The dragon at the cell i keeps gi coins. Every time the Knight steps to a cell with a dragon he has a choice  — to kill the dragon or just to pass through. The Knight is very strong and dexterous, so it is not a problem for him to kill any dragon on his way. If a dragon is killed the Knight gets all the gold dragon possessed.

When the Knight steps to the cell with a princess, she wonders how many dragons he has killed. If that number is greater or equal to her beauty bi, the princess considers the Knight brave enough and instantly asks him to marry her. Being a true gentleman, the Knight cannot refuse and his adventure immediately ends.

The Knight loves the princess who lives in the cell number n and wants to marry her. Also during the journey he wants to collect as much gold as possible. Please help him to accomplish this task.

**Input**-

The first line of the input contains a single integer n (2 ≤ n ≤ 2·105) — the number of cells. The next n-1 lines describe cells from 2 to n.

If the cell number i contains a dragon, the i-th line of the input contains letter "d" followed by a single integer gi (1 ≤ gi ≤ 104) — the number of coins the dragon keeps. The letter and the integer are separated by a single space.

If the cell number i contains a princess, the i-th line of the input contains letter "p" followed by a single integer bi (1 ≤ bi ≤ 2·105) — the beauty of the princess. The letter and the integer are separated by a single space. It is guaranteed that the last cell contains a princess.

**Output**-

On the first line of the output print a single integer — the maximum number of gold coins the Knight can collect. On the second line print a single integer k — the number of dragons to kill. The third line should contain k integers — the numbers of the cells where the Knight should kill a dragon. The cell numbers should be printed in the increasing order.

If there are several optimal solutions, output any of them. If the Knight can't marry his beloved princess, just print -1 in the first line of the output.

**Examples**:

**sample input**:

6

d 10

d 12

p 2

d 1

p 2

**sample output**:

13

2

3 5

**sample input**:

6

d 10

d 12

p 2

d 1

p 3

**sample output**:

-1

I submitted my solution but for some reason, it fails and I don't have access to the failed test cases.

I was hoping some fresh eyes might find the problem

My solution:

```
class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def insert(self, data):
        self.lst.append(data)
        self.heapify_up(len(self.lst) - 1)

    def pop_root(self):
        root = self.lst[0]
        last = self.lst.pop()

        if len(self.lst) > 0:
            self.lst[0] = last
            self.heapify_down(0, 0)

        return root

    def heapify_down(self, parent_idx, child_idx):
        if child_idx >= len(self.lst):
            return

        parent_greater_bool = self.lst[parent_idx] > self.lst[child_idx]

        if parent_greater_bool:
            self.lst[parent_idx], self.lst[child_idx] = self.lst[child_idx], self.lst[parent_idx]

        if parent_greater_bool or parent_idx == 0:
            self.heapify_down(child_idx, child_idx * 2 + 1)
            self.heapify_down(child_idx, child_idx * 2 + 2)

    def heapify_up(self, child_idx):
        parent_idx = (child_idx - 1) // 2

        if parent_idx < 0:
            return

        if self.lst[parent_idx] > self.lst[child_idx]:
            self.lst[parent_idx], self.lst[child_idx] = self.lst[child_idx], self.lst[parent_idx]
            self.heapify_up(parent_idx)

    def heap_sum(self):
        return sum([d.gold for d in self.lst])

    def indexes(self):
        return ' '.join(sorted([str(d.index) for d in self.lst]))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.lst)

    def __str__(self):
        res = ''
        for d in self.lst:
            res += f"index: {d.index}, gold: {d.gold} | "
        return res


class NotValidCharacter(Exception):
    pass


class Dragon:

    def __init__(self, index, gold):
        self.index = index
        self.gold = gold

    def __str__(self):
        return f"index: {self.index}, gold: {self.gold}"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.gold < other.gold


def dragons_and_princesses():
    heap = MinHeap()
    try:
        length = int(input("insert the length of the map\n"))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("The map length must be integer")

    if length < 2 or length > 200000:
        while length < 2 or length > 200000:
            try:
                length = int(input("insert the length of the map (2 - 200,000)\n"))
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError("The map length must be integer")

    for i in range(1, length):
        try:
            character, value = input().split()
            if character not in ['d', 'p']:
                raise NotValidCharacter('You can only enter dragons and princesses')
            value = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Make sure you enter 'd' or 'p' and following integer")

        if character == 'd':
            heap.insert(Dragon(i + 1, value))

        if character == 'p':
            if i == length - 1:
                if value > len(heap):
                    print(-1)
                else:
                    print(heap.heap_sum())
                    print(len(heap))
                    print(heap.indexes())

            elif value <= len(heap) and i != length - 1:
                while value <= len(heap):
                    heap.pop_root()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dragons_and_princesses()
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your own test cases, or using `set_trace` or `print()` statements to check whether your output is what you expect at each step?

Comment: I'd probably start by writing some randomized tests for the MinHeap.  It'd also be easier to offer advice if you explained the logic behind your solution -- it's not immediately obvious from reading the code what the heap is even used for.  If I were tackling this my first attempt would involve using `itertools.combinations` to figure out for each princess which combination of dragons I should have killed prior to that point, but I assume you're doing something cleverer that you haven't explained.

Comment: I'm using MinHeap so that if the knight encounters a princess with a beauty that is equal to or smaller than the amount of dragons the knight killed so far before he encounters the final princess, The dragon with the smallest amount of gold will be deleted from the heap until the size of the heap is smaller than the beauty level of the current princess.

Comment: In the first example, is the second `p 2` meant to be a `p 1`? If not, how do you kill the `d 1` dragon and not marry the second `p 2`? If you don't kill the `d 1` dragon why is your gold `13` rather than `12`?

Comment: @JonSG It supposes to be `p 2`. when the knight encounters the first `p 2` the `d 10` is removed from the heap and because of that, the killing amount reduces to 1.

Comment: Also if it wasn't clear from the explanation, the knight goal is to marry the final princess

Comment: @JonSG the second `p 2` is the final princess he doesn't need to get past her.
When he gets there he has 13 gold from killing the second dragon and the third dragon

Comment: You should always include a link to the original problem wherever you can. For reference, this is it -> https://codeforces.com/problemsets/acmsguru/problem/99999/548